# Return the foreground window from two windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

In `win32` programming, given two overlapped windows, `w1` and `w2`, how to get the foreground window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetForegroundWindow()` gets you the *actual* foreground window (the window with the current focus). There can be only 1 window in the foreground at a time.

If neither of your 2 windows are the foreground window, then there is no API available to *directly* determine which window is higher on the z-order than the other window. You would have to determine that manually, by enumerating windows using `EnumWindows()` and `EnumChildWindows()`.  Windows are enumerated in accordance to their z-orders.

For example:

```
struct myEnumInfo
{
    HWND hwnd1;
    HWND hwnd2;
    HWND hwndOnTop;
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    myEnumInfo *info = (myEnumInfo*) lParam;

    // is one of the HWNDs found?  If so, return it...
    if ((hwnd == info->hwnd1) || (hwnd == info->hwnd2))
    {
        info->hwndOnTop = hwnd;
        return FALSE; // stop enumerating
    }

    return TRUE; // continue enumerating
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    myEnumInfo *info = (myEnumInfo*) lParam;

    // is one of the HWNDs found?  If so, return it...
    if ((hwnd == info->hwnd1) || (hwnd == info->hwnd2))
    {
        info->hwndOnTop = hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }

    // enumerate this window's children...
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, &EnumChildProc, lParam);

    // is one of the HWNDs found?  If so, return it...
    if (info->hwndOnTop)
        return FALSE; // stop enumerating

    return TRUE; // continue enumerating
}

HWND WhichOneIsOnTop(HWND hwnd1, HWND hwnd2)
{
    // is one of the HWNDs null? If so, return the other HWND...
    if (!hwnd1) return hwnd2;
    if (!hwnd2) return hwnd1;

    // is one of the HWNDs in the actual foreground? If so, return it...
    HWND fgWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    if ((fgWnd) && ((fgWnd == hwnd1) || (fgWnd == hwnd2)))
        return fgWnd;

    myEnumInfo info;
    info.hwnd1 = hwnd1;
    info.hwnd1 = hwnd2;
    info.hwndOnTop = NULL;

    // are the HWNDs both children of the same parent?
    // If so, enumerate just that parent...
    HWND parent = GetAncestor(hwnd1, GA_PARENT);
    if ((parent) && (GetAncestor(hwnd2, GA_PARENT) == parent))
    {
        EnumChildWindows(parent, &EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)&info);
    }
    else
    {
        // last resort!! Enumerate all top-level windows and their children,
        // looking for the HWNDs wherever they are...
        EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&info);
    }

    return info.hwndOnTop;
}
```

Comment: The [foreground window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#foreground-and-background-windows) and the [Z order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#z-order) are separate concepts. Indeed, *"a **topmost window** overlaps all other non-topmost windows, regardless of whether it is the active or foreground window."*

Comment: @IInspectable I fixed it

Comment: When I use `EnumWindows()`, it returns many invisible windows (e.g. I have one opened window, it returns many windows), even though I use `IsWindowVisible` and `IsIconic` to remove invisible windows. What should I do to get the windows opened in my desktop?

Comment: @Feiying just ignore the windows you are not interested in. You have 2 HWNDs, simply pass them into your enum callbacks, and return the 1st HWND that is found.

Comment: How to confirm the first HWND passed into my callback function is the one I want? For example, I opened 1 window, `enumWindows()` pass 5 window HWNDs to my callback function. What should I do to filter these HWNDs? I tried using `IsWindowVisible()` and `IsIconic()`, but it still has many windows.

Comment: @Feiying You don't need to filter the windows, that is just wasted overhead. You already know the two `HWND`s you are interested in, just compare them as-is to the enumerated windows. Those are simple pointer comparisons. As I said, you can pass BOTH `HWND`s into the callbacks AT THE SAME TIME, and then return whichever `HWND` is found first. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the code. I think I have understood how to compare them now. I have one more small question, does `enumWindow()` start to enumerate the topmost window first?

Comment: @Feiying windows are enumerated in z-order from top to bottom. There can be more than one topmost window, which are enumerated before non-topmost windows. But only 1 window will have input focus at a time.

Comment: Hi, I see. Thank you very much for your time! It is really helpful for my study!